# Spring-Camel (camel logs by default goes console appender)

Tags: spring, log4j, apache-camel

I am facing one strange problem , I am working on one batch application using below tech STACK 
Spring (IOC container) , spring batch , Hibernate ,  camel and Log4J for logging 
I have configured  log4J for file appender only and my all application logs goes to my log file , but strange thing is that  all Camel logs goes to console appender (I have no console apender configured on my log4J properties file)

**Spring – Camel Integration is XMl element :**

```
 <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <routeBuilder ref="smtBatchRouter" />
    </camelContext>
```

**My Log4J configuration:**

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, file
log4j.logger.org.apache=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.directwebremoting=OFF
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=OFF
log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.file=myapp.log
log4j.appender.file.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.file.bufferedIO=false
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.' dd-MM-yyyy
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%-15.15t] %-5p %-30.30c{1} - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.threshold=TRACE
```

**Sample Camel Log that I am getting in console :**

```
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.11.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 4.009 seconds
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - sftp://xyz.com/smtDataFolder] INFO org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations - JSCH -> Connecting to localhost port 22
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - sftp://xyz.com/smtDataFolder] INFO org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations - JSCH -> Connection established
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - sftp://xyz.com/smtDataFolder] INFO org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations - JSCH -> Remote version string: SSH-1.99-OpenSSH_4.6
```

Comment: Is it only the JSCH logging you see in the console?

Comment: Thanks for reply, no actually its not only JSCH logging , I am seeing hibernate initialization logging as well in console .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it.
Run your application with the flag:
    `-Dlog4j.debug`
It will add diagnostic information to your console. In my case it was

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
```

So I just deleted redundant `slf4j-jdk14-1.7.9.jar` and left only `slf4j-log4j12-1.7.19.jar`.