# Log4j creates "target" folder with empty "camel-spring-redis-test.log" logfile in it

Tags: java, log4j, apache-camel

I have simple log, and it does do it's job, but for unknown reasons it also creates folder `"target"` and empty `"camel-spring-redis-test.log"` inside. The `log.properties` below

```
    log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
    log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Append=false
    log4j.appender.file.File=res/logfile.log
    log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
    log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Maybe the reason in Apache Camel, used in this project?
How to forbid creation of theese things?

Comment: Ah yeah sadly the log4j.properties file was not in the test directory - this will be fixed in next Camel releases: https://github.com/apache/camel/commit/ae6ea22833b9705472e16c7d0b1663508057f29e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It involves using Spring Redis component (http://camel.apache.org/spring-redis.html). The bungle of this component contains the file log4.properties
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.camel/camel-spring-redis/2.12.0/log4j.properties?av=f

You have to work on configuring the logging in your infrastructure to forbid creation camel-spring-redis-test.log.
What kind of server are you using for running Apache Camel?  The solution will depend on your servers log settings.

Comment: Camel runs on my local machine, without any server

Comment: You should put your log4j.properties in the root resources folder of your project. For example: `src\main\resources\log4j.properties`.

Comment: These two topics can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716824/where-how-does-log4j-look-for-a-log4j-properties-file
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594689/external-log4j-xml-file

Comment: Another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866259/log4j-picking-up-wrong-properties-file

Comment: Thank you for interesting topics, I got them, but problem they describe has small difference with mine. That's good example in the 1-st link, and if I properly understood, that problem's in missing `.config` file (log4j can't find the path and use default configurations). Maybe I used incorrect words, but my logger works unquestioningly, it writes log where i pointed to it to do, but besides it my logger creates folder "target" with empty "camel-spring-redis-test.log" inside. It doesn't disturbes me, but there is some some mistake I'm trying to detect.

Comment: Your application use not only one configuration of log4j. I think application discover your own log4j.properties after when log4j.properties from Spring Redist and create folder an file before your own configuration to be used. You need to some how to disable discovering log4j.properties from Spring Redist before your own config. I think, using `log4j.xml` or, maybe starting your application with key `-Dlog4j.configuration=...`  pointing to your config file will help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761729/spring-camel-camel-logs-by-default-goes-console-appender something like my problem

Comment: You're absolutely allright, after some manipulations i found that `target` folder creation ends before my `PropertyConfigurator.configure("res/config.properties");` starts to work (because logging works even if i remove this code)

Comment: Is your log4j config file have name `config.properties`?  If so, rename it to log4j.properties and try again.

Comment: Just because log4j.properties is default value of log4j configuration file name :) You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are right, because Apache Camel uses log4j too (via sfl4j).
This [link](http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-log4j.html) shows how to enable logs on Camel.

You may try addind this line to your log.properties and see if it works

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.camel=OFF
```

Comment: or this for redis: log4j.logger.org.apache.camel.component.redis=OFF

Comment: And this one has no effect( What the amazing persistence!